# typescript ionic 3 prepend call to all constructors

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

how can I call redirect if not logedIn in all pages constructors without repeating myself?

```
  constructor(protected appCtrl: AppController) {
    this.appCtrl.redirectIfNotLogedIn();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest having a `BaseComponent` class that implements [`ionViewCanEnter`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/) that returns a boolean value.

> Runs before the view can enter. This can be used as a sort of "guard" in authenticated views where you need to check permissions before the view can enter

```
export class BaseComponent{
  constructor(){}

  ionViewCanEnter(){
    //check if logged in or not and return the boolean value
  }

}
```

This component can be extended by all your pages.

```
  export class MyPage extends BaseComponent{
  //...
  }
```

You *could try to* call your `this.appCtrl.redirectIfNotLogedIn();` in the constructor of BaseComponent but I suggest you use the NavGuard.